# Channel Form Asset CSS not working

Tags: safecracker, css

I need to use the datepicker for a Channel Form and I've included the following as per the docs:

```
<link href="{path=css/_ee_channel_form_css}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```

However, this doesn't work...it gives me a 404 Not Found message:

"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"
and tries to link to http://www.mydevserver.com/css/_ee_channel_form_css

Can anyone help me out and point me in the right direction please?

Thanks!
Dan

ps. running latest version of EE